# Generating Squares by the use of awk command

Tags: awk

I have a text file named **prac** which has the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 in seperate lines. I want to generate the squares of these numbers using AWK command.

For this i wrote the following command:

`awk 'BEGIN { a = $1; a = a ^ 2; print "a =", a }' prac`

But the output shows `a = 0`

Please let me know my mistakes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because your code is in a `BEGIN` block.  The special `BEGIN` block is triggered once, just *before* reading the the first line of input from the first input file (likewise, the special `END` block is triggered once *after* reading the last line of input). You want to execute your block of code for *each* line:

```
awk '{ printf("a = %s\n", $1*$1) }' prac
```

or closer to your original code,

```
awk '{ a = $1*$1; print "a =", a }' prac
```